# Joi validation using joi.object

Tags: typescript, joi, hapi

trying to learn Typescript and using Joi with Hapi to write some API code and query validation. Ran into an issue where this works:

```
query: joi.object({
            apiKey: joi.string().required()
        })
```

but this does not:

```
query: {
            apiKey: joi.string().required()
        }
```

Does anyone know what is happening here? I get a runtime error in the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Joi 16` onwards you have to wrap your schema in `Joi.object`. This is the reason why it is not working in the second case. If you want to use the second way, you need to use `Joi 15`

Comment: oh...makes sense